# Array to string conversion Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Требуется выводить через droplist список категорий при создании страницы нового продукта.

Мой код:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выпадает следующая ошибка конвертации данных:

PHP Notice – yii\base\ErrorException

**Array to string conversion**

Никогда не сталкивался с ней. Помогите, пожалуйста!

Comment: в общем-то, возможно потому, что у вас написано `<?=` а это короткое обозначение `<?php echo `.  то есть все что вы пытаетесь сделать это пытается интерпретатор вывести эхом....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В общем-то, возможно потому, что у вас написано `<?=` а это короткое обозначение `<?php echo`.  То есть все, что вы пытаетесь сделать внутри - это пытается интерпретатор вывести через `echo`....

Соответственно, надо перед `$categories`  написать тег `<?php`  а перед `$form->field...` написать `echo`

Должно сработать.

Comment: Отлично, спасибо! Был крайне невнимателен:)